# Solr/ SimplePostTool cannot index any file 503 error

Tags: solr

I am new to Solr and trying to figure out the basics of indexing one file. I've started with this tutorial http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html, but being on windows I am hitting a wall when it comes to running the command to index.

This is what my output looks like:

```
SolrCloud example is running, please visit http://localhost:8983/solr"


C:\Projects\solr-5.1.0>java -Dc=gettingstarted -Dtype=text/csv  -Dfiletypes=cs -
jar example/exampledocs/post.jar Z:/Indexer/tfs/ShippingOptionsPerRecipient.aspx
.cs
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update usi
ng content-type text/csv...
POSTing file ShippingOptionsPerRecipient.aspx.cs to [base]
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #503 (Service Unavailable) for u
rl: http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">503</int><int name="QTime">4057</i
nt></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">No registered leader was found after
waiting for 4000ms , collection: gettingstarted slice: shard1</str><int name="co
de">503</int></lst>
</response>
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException
: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/ge
ttingstarted/update
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/updat
e...
Time spent: 0:00:04.255
```

Unfortunately, I can't find much documentation on any of these errors.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: were you trying to use something similar to this **bin/post -c gettingstarted example/exampledocs/books.csv**

Comment: So the command in my code comes from this website https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Post+Tool#PostTool-Windows, which is referenced in the other tutorial as an afterthought for windows users

Comment: ok Before adding data using post, have you tried through admin console provided. And is the gettingstarted collection present. It says issue with this part "/gettingstarted/update". So either it could be with collection itself, or with update. You can use healthcheck option, to get status like this **"bin/solr healthcheck -c gettingstarted"**. Also as per this line in your log **POSTing file ShippingOptionsPerRecipient.aspx.cs*, i did not understand .aspx.csv, a thats what you gave in command. Try indexing with simple xml and move onto others. happy coding

Comment: Thanks. Ran the bin/solr healthcheck, but I couldn't even get connected to zoo keeper. I'm thinking maybe my servers aren't talking t each other properly at this point...